# state variable is getting the previous value on input[type===radio]. or working on double click only

Tags: reactjs, input, radio-button

This is the code for my react project. I am trying to get the value assigned to the input type radio but it is not working as expected. check my code when I am using onchange the "value" in my handleSelect is getting the correct value of input assigned but the value assigning to the selecttopup is the previously selected input

```
const handleSelectTopup = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    setSelectedTopup(value);
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(selectTopup);
  };
<div className="topup-checkboxes" onChange={handleSelectTopup}>
                  <div className="topup-checkbox-item">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      id="topup-g1"
                      value="1"
                      name="g"
                    ></input>
                    <label for="topup-g1" className="topup-checkbox-item-label">
                      <span>From 500 to 3000 points</span>
                      <strong>
                        {" "}
                        + 15% <sub>free</sub>
                      </strong>
                      <LiaWalletSolid className="wallet-icon"></LiaWalletSolid>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="topup-checkbox-item">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      id="topup-g2"
                      value="2"
                      name="g"
                    ></input>
                    <label for="topup-g2" className="topup-checkbox-item-label">
                      <span>From 300 to 499 points</span>
                      <strong>
                        {" "}
                        + 10% <sub>free</sub>
                      </strong>
                      <LiaWalletSolid className="wallet-icon"></LiaWalletSolid>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="topup-checkbox-item">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      id="topup-g3"
                      value="3"
                      name="g"
                    ></input>
                    <label for="topup-g3" className="topup-checkbox-item-label">
                      <span>From 150 to 299 points</span>
                      <strong>
                        {" "}
                        + 5% <sub>free</sub>
                      </strong>
                      <LiaWalletSolid className="wallet-icon"></LiaWalletSolid>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="topup-checkbox-item">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      id="topup-g4"
                      value="4"
                      name="g"
                      // checked={selectTopup === 4 ? "checked" : ""}
                    ></input>
                    <label for="topup-g4" className="topup-checkbox-item-label">
                      <span>From 50 to 149 points</span>
                      <strong>
                        {" "}
                        + 0% <sub>free</sub>
                      </strong>
                      <LiaWalletSolid className="wallet-icon"></LiaWalletSolid>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting state only changes it for the next render. In your case, if value in handleSelected is getting correct value then this should work just fine. The reason for previous input showing in console is because you pass to console.log() the state at the moment the console.log is called. You can see explanation on this in react documentation [here](https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot). So basicly with `setSelectedTopup(value)` you tell React to change `selectTopup` state to `value` for the next render, and then with `console.log(selectTopup)`  you logg current state, that is why you get "previous" input showing in console.

Let's see what happens in your example:

Let's say that current selected input is first one, so current state in `selecTopup` is 1 and now you selected the second input. Since change is made the handleSelectTopup function is called. Inside your function you have:

```
const value = e.target.value;

setSelectedTopup(value);
console.log(e.target);
console.log(selectTopup);
```

first you asign `e.target.value` to `value` variable, then with `setSelectedTopup(value)` you tell React to set `selectTopup` to `value` (which is 2 in our example) for the next render. Remember, you just told React to do it, it didn't happen yet. Then you log `e.target` and `selectTopup`. Since current state of `selectTopup` is 1 you will logg 1 to console. After this function is done the React will render your component again and the state of `selectTopup` will be changed to 2.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i still unable to get what you are trying to say. do you mean that the state that I am logging is showing me the previous value but the current new value is already assigned to it?

Comment: I read the document link you provided from that what I understand is that the console.log() is printing the previous state but in real on react the actual state was updated? means in my state variable actual value is used?

Comment: but if it is like that it is messing my codes and logic on which I want to work

Comment: I just added example in my answer to clarify this a little bit more. I don't know what exacly do you want to do with this function in your real code but if you need some work with new value you can just use `value`  variable for it. After this function is done, React will render your component again and state of `selectTopup` will change to new value.